# Pushing data to a kafka server with Logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack, kafka-producer-api, logstash-configuration

i have a logstash conf file that looks like this:

```
input {

      jdbc {

            jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//the-s2.db.oracle.yn:1521/DPP2.mind.com"
            jdbc_user => "STG_TEST"
            jdbc_password => "cddcdcd"
            parameters => {"orderid" => 1212332365}
            statement => "select PO_SEARCH_IL_ID,ORDER_DATE,REF_1,SHIPPING_WINDOW_START,SHIPPING_WINDOW_END FROM ods.po_search_il where PO_SEARCH_IL_ID =:orderid "
            schedule => "* * * * *"
            clean_run => true


    }

}

output {
        kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "mykafkaservername.kn:9092"
        topic_id => ["test3"]
                }
        }
```

the Script run the topic test3 is created into the kafka server but no data in there.

[image: snapshot of the kafka UI]

Does somebody could help on that issue?

Comment: Are you fixed on using Logstash? if you just want to get data from Oracle into Kafka you're probably better off using Kafka Connect.

Comment: yes as i dont know how to use it.